# Why does ImageView setImageResource() sets image size to match_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Here is the XML layout.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_textSize"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="clickPlay"
        android:src="@drawable/pause"
        />

<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restart_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/play_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="clickRestart"
        android:src="@drawable/restart"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
```

Here is a method clickPlay()

```
public void clickPlay(View v) {
    if (playerCurrent != null && playerCurrent.isPlaying()) {
        playerCurrent.pause();
        playerBackground.pause();
        imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        mVolumeSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imgRestart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mIsPlaying = false;
    } else {
        playerCurrent.start();
        playerBackground.start();
        imgPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        mVolumeSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgRestart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mIsPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

However, when I change image from Pause to Play, Play image get size of `match_parent`, but when I press again and image changes to Pause image, it gets a normal size of `wrap_content`.

Both Play and Pause images are identical!

Here is the image of how it looks before and after (made them colored so you better view the size)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using the same drawable in both cases to rule out issues with the drawable resources.

Comment: Are you play and pause drawables same size in pixels?

Comment: @Lamorak Yes, identical

Comment: And are they in the same folder? This is weird..

Comment: @Lamorak Of course, both in /drawable-large (7in tablets resources). Yes, weird indeed. I actually did not notice this on mobile devices before I started testing on tablets.

Comment: @sandalone Have you tried using the same drawable for both `ImageView` yet? Just temporarily for debugging purposes of course.

Comment: Also try to specify the image density. Having images in just `drawable-large` might behave unpredictable on different tablets. According to real image size rename your folder to `drawable-large-hdpi` (`xhdpi` of whatever)

Comment: @Lamorak All *dpi attributes are disregarded by Android ;). You should never rely on them. Check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was NOT an issue with Android SDK. It was an issue either with Android Emulator or Android Studio.

Namely, when I uninstalled the app from the emulator and did `Build->Rebuild Project`, the bug was gone. Obviously either of these two did not properly refresh images in `/res` folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  XML worked fine until I replaced the image with a call to setImageResource.  The trick was to have:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in the XML.  Don't know what that fixed it, but it did.

My full layout for my image looks like:

```
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@drawable/charts_button"
            android:contentDescription="Nautical Charts View"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```